# Download and rename file from Server using php script

Tags: php, file, download, rename

I am storing all my files like "8asd98asd9as7d98asd9.file" and rerieve the "real" filename from a mysql-database: id (INT) AI PK, pathOnServer TEXT NOT NULL, realFilename VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL.

I need a script which allows me to access the files like "www.website.com/getFile?id=2" which downloads the file and renames it to "realFilename".

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe this code will do a trick you look for

```
<?php

   if(!is_numeric($_GET['id'])) { // We validate parameter
       echo 'Wrong parameter';
       exit();
   }

   $oDb = new mysqli("ip","user","pass","databasename"); // Connecting to database
   if($oDb->connect_errno) { // Check for an error
      echo 'Error';
      exit();
   }

   $oResult = $oDb->query('SELECT `pathOnServer`, `realFilename`
                           FROM --tablename--
                           WHERE id = '.(int)$_GET['id'].'
                           LIMIT 1'); // make query
   if($oResult->num_rows != 1) {
       echo 'No file found';
       exit();
   }

   $oQuery = $oResult->fetch_object();
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$oQuery->realFilename); // put special headers
   readfile($oQuery->pathOnServer.$oQuery->id); // put the file
?>
```

You could also add the header with filesize.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) HTTP Header to tell the Browser the name of your file and then use [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to load and echo said file.

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
$name = basename($path);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
readfile($path); 
exit;
```